# Is my reinforced concrete ceiling still safe?

Tags: water, concrete, ceiling, roof, damage

The ceiling of my Honk Kong flat has exposed corroded steel and crumbling concrete. The plaster easily falls out of there, and there are cracks in the roof.

- Is this fixable?
- Is this still safe?
- What can/should I do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a DIY question.  What does the building owner say about this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires an engineer on-site and includes multiple questions.

Comment: Please see the [help]. You need to ask a single question, which isn't purely a matter of opinion, and which doesn't require much more information than you have provided.

Comment: The flaking paint by itself is an indication of moisture issues. The fact that the concrete has spalled off indicates that the rebar inside is rusting (and expanding, which pops the concrete off). Rusted rebar is not as strong as un-rusted rebar. So there little doubt that this structure is not as strong as it was intended to be. Whether or not it's become a safety issue can only be determined by a professional on-site inspection. It's not something you can ignore. It's not going away, and worst-case is another [Champlain Towers](https://www.google.com/search?q=champlain+towers) incident.

Answer (score 3):

If you're near a salty body of water, the salt water can cause corrosion like this, where the corrosion generates pressure that spalls the concrete. Most likely, though, this is just old reinforced concrete with corrosion (and spalling) caused by moisture.

The high alkalinity of new concrete protects reinforcing steel from corrosion, even if the concrete is saturated with water. Unfortunately atmospheric CO₂ reacts with the concrete to nullify the high alkalinity that provides this corrosion protection. For well placed concrete, the low alkalinity spreads inward from the surfaces at a rate of about 0.04" per year. Search the web for "rebar passivation layer" if you want more information.

My expectation is that your rebar lost its passive layer and is now corroding from moisture. If there's still any strength left in the rebar, you would want to prevent further corrosion by stopping moisture from soaking into the concrete. With better pictures, ceiling thickness, rebar diameter and spacing, etc., I could give you safety and repair opinions for free over the tubes here, but you should get a local professional to actually look at this in person. Common structural pathologies based on local practices will be familiar to this person, and he'll also be able to notice things that you might have ignored as unimportant.